# Joining dataframes on multiple columns with one column toleranced?

Tags: pandas

Hi what would be an effective way to join two dataframes together on multiple columns, where all but a select number (one in this case) is not an exact match?

edit: on Ben's suggestions, ['A', 'B', 'D',] make up a unique ID for df1 and df2, and joins on df1 should be unique, and df1.shape != df2.shape.

i.e.:

```
df1
    A       B    C    D
1   Apple   21   10   a
2   Pear    90   12   a
3   Apple   31   11   b
4   Apple   71   14   c
5   Apple   45   15   d
6   Pear    14   13   b

df2
    A       B    E    D
1   Apple   22   50   a
2   Pear    89   46   a
3   Apple   30   56   b
4   Apple   72   60   c
```

Joining on ['A', 'B', 'D',] where B is has a tolerance and +/- 1. Resulting in

```
    A       B    C    D    E
1   Apple   21   10   a    50
2   Pear    90   12   a    46
3   Apple   31   11   b    56
4   Apple   71   14   c    60
5   Apple   45   15   d    NaN
6   Pear    14   13   b    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `merge_asof` with `tolerance`

```
pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('B'),df2.sort_values('B'),by=['A','D'],on='B',tolerance=1,direction='nearest')

Out[306]: 
       A   B   C  D     E
0   Pear  14  13  b   NaN
1  Apple  21  10  a  50.0
2  Apple  31  11  b  56.0
3  Apple  45  15  d   NaN
4  Apple  71  14  c  60.0
5   Pear  90  12  a  46.0
```

Comment: Sorry, I should elaborate, df1 and df2 are different shapes, and matches should be more or less unique and ['A', 'B, 'D'] would make up a unique ID for the row.

Comment: @RoyHan I did not do any change , and the output is match what you need , just you need get back the order

Comment: Thanks again Ben!